# simpletip help with dynamic content loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load content from the database using simpletip. My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a.regularsList').simpletip({
            onBeforeShow: function(){
                this.load('/regulars/tooltip', {id: $(this).attr("id")});
            }
        });
    })
```

I get that id is undefined. I don't understand what am i doing wrong since i am trying to access the value of the id attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current code `this` refers to `document`, instead use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loop here so that `this` refers to the anchor you want, like this:

```
$(function(){ //short for $(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.regularsList').each(function() {
     var a = this;
     $(this).simpletip({
        onBeforeShow: function(){
          this.load('/regulars/tooltip', { id: a.id });
        }
    });
});
```

Inside the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loop, `this` refers to the current `a.regularsList` element you're looking over, so you can just use `this.id` to get the `id` property.

Comment: Still it causes the same problem.

Comment: no matter if i use this.id or $(this).attr('id') i still get undefined in firebug console.

Comment: @user253530 - woops, `this` refers to their object inside that function, need to store a reference, check the updated answer :)

Comment: My code: <a class="regularsList" id="<?php echo $this->id;?>" href="/regulars/regulars/id/<?php echo $this->id;?>"><?php echo $this->name;?></a> I'm using partialLoop in zend_framework to display all the links.